# Como concatenar campos no linq e renomear

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Fiz um linq e não está dando certo a concatenação e a renomeação do mesmo. Veja:

```
var monta_arvore = (from rup in db.Ruptura
                                  from apr in db.Apresentacao.Where(ap => ap.Codigo_Apresentacao == rup.Codigo_Apresentacao)
                                  from pdv in db.PDV.Where(p => p.CodigoPDV == rup.CodigoPDV)
                                  from mot in db.Motivo.Where(m => m.IDMotivo == rup.IDMotivo)

                                  select new {
                                      rup.IDRuptura,
                                      rup.DataRuptura,
                                      rup.IDMotivo,
                                      mot.Motivo1,
                                      rup.IDOrigem,
                                      rup.CodigoPDV,
                                      pdv.UF,
                                      pdv.Cidade,
                                      pdv.Cnpj + " - " + pdv.Descricao as PDV,==>> Erro aqui
                                      rup.Codigo_Apresentacao,
                                      apr.Unidade_Negocio,
                                      apr.Franquia,
                                      apr.Descricao}).ToList().Distinct();
```

Comment: Acho que é isso: loja = pdv.Cnpj + " - " + pdv.Descricao

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em C#, um objeto anonimo, pode ser escrito da seguinte forma:

```
var a = new { texto, numero };
```

e o .net ira se encarregar de criar um objeto com propriedades com os nomes das referências que você passou como propriedades, `texto` e `numero`. Ou você pode nomear as propriedades, por exemplo:

```
var a = new { MeuText = texto, MeuNumero = numero };
```

E será acessível pelas propriedades `MeuTexto` e `MeuNumero`.

Você também pode mesclar.

```
var a = new { MeuText = texto, numero };
```

No seu caso, adicione uma nova propriedade, pois o .Net não saberá renomear a propriedade, dado que ela é dinâmica (concatena dois campos).

```
var monta_arvore = (from rup in db.Ruptura
                    from apr in db.Apresentacao.Where(ap => ap.Codigo_Apresentacao == rup.Codigo_Apresentacao)
                    from pdv in db.PDV.Where(p => p.CodigoPDV == rup.CodigoPDV)
                    from mot in db.Motivo.Where(m => m.IDMotivo == rup.IDMotivo)    
                    select new {
                                rup.IDRuptura,
                                rup.DataRuptura,
                                rup.IDMotivo,
                                mot.Motivo1,
                                rup.IDOrigem,
                                rup.CodigoPDV,
                                pdv.UF,
                                pdv.Cidade,
                                CnpjDescricao = pdv.Cnpj + " - " + pdv.Descricao,
                                rup.Codigo_Apresentacao,
                                apr.Unidade_Negocio,
                                apr.Franquia,
                                apr.Descricao})
                  .ToList()
                  .Distinct();
```

Comment: Conforme meu comentário, eu já havia respondido. Faltou um pouco mais de pesquisa de minha parte. Falhei em perguntar antes de quebrar a cabeça, devido eu ter que resolver em minutos, mas consegui e peço desculpas pelo post rápido sem pesquisa.

Comment: Tranquilo @pnet, as vezes esta dúvida pode ser a mesma de outros usuários e fica aqui o registro!. Se possível marque como resposta para indicar o caminho :) Obrigado!